# Python Dictionary stores only key values

Tags: python, dictionary, output

Guys I have this code :

```
text =  []
pos  =  {}
neg  =  {}
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
i = 0

with open('DATA/test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        i += 1
        token = word_tokenize(h.unescape(row[3].decode('utf-8')))
        # print(h.unescape(row[1] + ' ' + row[3].decode('utf8')))
        if row[1] == "0":
            pos[i] = {i: token}
        elif row[1] == "1":
            neg.update({i: token})

        text += token

text = nltk.Text(text)
neg  = nltk.Text(neg)
pos  = nltk.Text(pos)

print(pos)
```

I want each neg or pos to be in the format of {1: 'whatever'}, {2: 'another'} however I only get the key values such as: Text: 1 2 3 4 9 10 20 24...

Comment: Where is your dictionary? In what line are you trying to *get* its key-values?

Comment: `nltk.Text` expects an iterable. The iterable in dict is the set of keys. What do you expect when you call `nltk.Text(pos)` exactly?

Comment: I want the output to be [{1: 'something'},{2: 'something else'}] but my output at the moment is <Text: 1 2 3 4 9 10 20 24...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `nltk.Text` want an iterable of `str`. When a `dict` is used as an iterable, only the keys are iterated over.

You can get an iterable over `(key, value)` pairs by calling `.items()` on the `dict`, but that won't satisfy the `nltk.Text` constructor.

Comment: It's not only that. If you expect [{1: "something"}, {2: "something else"}] then pos and neg should be lists, and you should use pos.append({i: ...}). To satisfy nltk.Text() you can store them as strings at creation time, or run pos = map(str, pos) later.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the responses helped!